# windows 8 monitor turn off or enter sleep mode

Tags: windows-8, display, sleep, resolution

I installed a retail version of windows 8 x64. 
However, after the installation process my crt monitor shuts down or enters in sleep mode and I'm unable to turn it on.

Every time I turn on computer the monitor fails after windows picture disapear.

I try with a recent LCD monitor and everything is fine. I've tried put a worst resolution and saved it, and I switch back to CRT monitor but doesn't work.

Anyone with brillant ideas?

Comment: Are you connecting the LCD and CRT with the same kind of cable (I assume VGA)?

Comment: Does the CRT work fine in safe mode? Did you try updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: I'm using VGA connect. When I had the LCD on I updated nvidia drivers

Comment: Safe mode is available on CRT monitor